# XNA 4 - Texture clone

Tags: xna, texture2d, blit

I need to copy content of one texture2d to another (both stored in VRAM)?
Is this even possible without using RTT or any additional RAM-VRAM transfers?
Just pure BLIT between two textures in VRAM.

Thanks in advance! I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Do you want to copy it pixel by pixel into another texture with different dimensions, just make a copy of it with another name, or mix it with another texture like two semi-transparent images?

Comment: I have one RTT and I am rendering alpha mask inside it. And I need to have function for making its exact copy for later use (Any following rendering into RTT should not modify the cloned one).

Comment: The reason I dont want to use RTT is just because I dont need to modify the cloned texture anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [RenderTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rendertarget%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) does not remove the data from VRAM.  It can be reused in a subsequent draw call as a texture without returning it to RAM.  However, if you need to perform operations on it in code, like with `getData()`, then it will move out of video memory.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought. BLIT can be implemented only by using RTT in XNA.